# Traverse backwards through array with random start and end

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I have a function that takes an array, along with a random head and tail index values. I am trying to traverse the entire array backwards from the tail value until the head value, but it seems that some values are being skipped.

Here is my logic:

```
currentRec = tail;

while (currentRec != head)
{
    // get current record from array and do stuff (i.e. myArray[currentRec])


    if (currentRec == 0)
    {
        currentRec = MAX_RECORDS - 1; // MAX_RECORDS is 200
    }
    else
    {
        currentRec--;
    }
}
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Now would be a good time to start learning how to use your debugger.

Comment: Please provide a ___[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)___

Comment: As written, the code is correct. This is supposing you're talking about standard arrays, and all those variables being positive integers.

Comment: I don't see any `array` here.. Wait, lemme put on my glasses.. ummm.. Nope, still cant see..

Comment: you're telling me the tale of a tail, but I can't see one...

Comment: @Banex Yes, standard array. The `while` loop is looping through index values.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Sorry, forgot to add that line. Updated.

Comment: The code seems correct, Can you show the complete code and some output

Comment: If you wish the `head` element to also be processed, the loop condition causes it to not be, otherwise looks correct assuming the array is indexed `0..(MAX_RECORDS - 1)` and `head` and `tail` are both integers in that range.

Comment: @ILostMySpoon If the head coincides with the tail do you need to traverse all the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is not processing the final element at index `head`. If you want to process all elements from `tail` to `head` *inclusive* then you need to change your logic a little:

```
currentRec = tail;

while (1)
{
    // get current record from array and do stuff (i.e. myArray[currentRec])

    if (currentRec == head)   // if we've just processed the last (i.e. head) element
    {
        break;                // exit loop
    }

    if (currentRec == 0)      // otherwise bump currentRec and repeat...
    {
        currentRec = MAX_RECORDS - 1; // MAX_RECORDS is 200
    }
    else
    {
        currentRec--;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you have the additional requirement that when `head == tail` then you want to process all elements in the array then you need to add a little more logic:

```
currentRec = tail;
done = false;

while (1)
{    
    // get current record from array and do stuff (i.e. myArray[currentRec])

    if (done)           // if we've just processed the last (head) record
    {
        break;          // exit loop
    }

    if (currentRec == 0)
    {
        currentRec = MAX_RECORDS - 1; // MAX_RECORDS is 200
    }
    else
    {
        currentRec--;
    }

    if (currentRec == head)
    {
        done = true;    // set flag to indicate that the next iteration will be the last
    }
}
```